# Recursion / Recursion Trace

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to see the recursion trace of this function but why do i get **"None"** output?

```
def fnc(k):
    if k == 0:
        return 0
    fnc(k-1)
    fnc(k-1)
    fnc(k-1)
    fnc(k-1)
```

Comment: Under what circumstances do you get an output of `None`? How are you calling the function, which parameters are you passing to it?

Comment: @riskypenguin Tried to call it like print(fnc(10))

Comment: Whenever `k != 0`, you have no `return` statements, so your function returns nothing, hence `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is actually pretty easily identified by evaluating your code by hand for small parameters. Let's say you pass `k = 1` to `fnc`:

```
def fnc(k):
    # k == 1 != 0, so we skip the return
    if k == 0:
        return 0

    # Now we call fnc four times with k - 1 = 0 as an argument
    # All four function calls will return 0
    # But we don't use the returned value in any way (no assignment, no return)
    fnc(k - 1)
    fnc(k - 1)
    fnc(k - 1)
    fnc(k - 1)

    # The function ends without returning anything, therefore the return value is None
```

I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but if you want the base case value returned, this will do:

```
def fnc(k):
    if k == 0:
        return 0

    return fnc(k-1)
```

Please compare these two functions, maybe step through it by hand and try to understand what exactly is going on.